# Pandas DataFrame groupby apply and re-expand along grouped axis

Tags: python, dataset, pandas

Say I have a dataframe

```
            A   B   C   D
2019-01-01  1   10  100 12
2019-01-02  2   20  200 23
2019-01-03  3   30  300 34
```

And an array to group the columns by

```
array([0, 1, 0, 2])
```

I wish to group the dataframe by the array (on the column axis), apply a function, then return a Series with length of the number of columns, containing the result of the applied function on each column.

So, for the above (with the applied function taking the group's sum), would want to output:

```
A    606
B     60
C    606
D     69
dtype: int64
```

My best attempt:

```
func = lambda a: np.full(a.shape[1], np.sum(a.values))
df.groupby(groups, axis=1).apply(func)

0    [606, 606]
1          [60]
2          [69]
dtype: object
```

(in this example the applied function returns equal values inside a group, but this can't be guaranteed for the real case)

I can not see how to do this with pandas grouping syntax, unless I am missing something. Could anyone lend a hand, thanks!

Comment: What is your desired output for that example?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


groups = [0, 1, 0, 2]

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3],
                   'B': [10, 20, 30],
                   'C': [100, 200, 300],
                   'D': [12, 23, 34]})

temp = df.apply(sum).to_frame()

temp.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(
    np.stack([temp.index, groups]),
    names=("df columns", "groups")
)

temp_filter = temp.groupby(level=1).agg(sum)

result = temp.join(temp_filter, rsuffix='0'). \
    set_index(temp.index.get_level_values(0))["00"]

# df columns
# A    606
# B     60
# C    606
# D     69
# Name: 00, dtype: int64
```